# When setting a font-size in CSS, what is the real height of the letters?

Tags: css, browser, fonts

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353761/when-setting-css-font-size-in-pixels-does-the-value-refer-to-the-width-or-heigh) whose answer in essence says:

> The height - specifically from the top of the ascenders (e.g., 'h' or 'l' (el)) to the bottom of the descenders (e.g., 'g' or 'y')

This has also been my experiance. I.e. in 14px Arial the height of the letter `K` (the baseline height) is about 10px.

[The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) say nothing about the calculated font-size so I'm guessing this is browser-specific, but I could not find any reference to it.

(Other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373460/what-exactly-is-the-font-size) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073602/css-font-size-specifics) ask roughly the same thing but sadly no answer gives a satisfying explanation..)

Is there any documentation on why the font-size seems to be the size "from ascenders to descendes"?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[image]

### Some background on the subject

Back when letters were created on metal, the em referred to the size of each block that the letter would be engraved on, and that size was determined by the capital M because it usually takes up the most space.

Now a days, font developers create their fonts on a computer without the limitations of a physical piece of metal so while the em still exists, its nothing more than an imaginary boundary in the software; thus prone to being manipulated or disregarded altogether.

### Standards

In an [OpenType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/default.htm) font, the em size is supposed to be set to 1000 units. And in [TrueType](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/) fonts, the em size is usually either 1024 or 2048.

The most accurate way to define a font style is to use EM that way when you define a font-size for use, the dimension does not refer to the pixel height of the font, but to the fonts x height which is determined by the distance between the baseline and the mean line of the font.

For the record 1 [PT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) is about 0.35136mm.  And PX is 1 "dot" on your screen which is defined by the dots per square inch or resolution of your screen and thus different from screen to screen and is the worst way to define a font size.

### Unit conversion

This is a pretty good read if you enjoy literature that makes your eyes bleed like me..  [International unification of typopgrahic measurements](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/metric-typo/hoch67.pdf)

```
1 point (Truchet)                    |  0.188 mm
1 point (Didot)                      |  0.376 mm or 1/72 of a French royal inch
1 point (ATA)                        |  0.3514598 mm or 0.013837 inch
1 point (TeX)                        |  0.3514598035 mm or 1/72.27 inch
1 point (Postscript)                 |  0.3527777778 mm or 1/72 inch
1 point (l’Imprimerie nationale, IN) |  0.4 mm
1 pica (ATA)                         |  4.2175176 mm = 12 points (ATA)
1 pica (TeX)                         |  4.217517642 mm = 12 points (TeX)
1 pica (Postscript)                  |  4.233333333 mm = 12 points (Postscript)
1 cicero                             |  4.531 mm = 12 points (Didot)
```

Resolutions

```
µm  :  10.0    20.0    21.2    40.0    42.3    80.0    84.7    100.0    250.0    254.0
dpi :  2540    1270    1200    635     600     317     300     254      102      100
```

### Standards are only worth so much..

The actual size of one fonts glyphs vs another font are always going vary dependent on:

1. how the developer designed the font glyphs when creating the font,
2. and how the browser renders those characters.  No two browsers are going to be exactly the same.
3. the resolution and [ppi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixels_per_inch) of the screen viewing the font.

#### Example

As an example of how common it is for font developers to manipulate the geometry.. Back when Apple created the Zapfino script font, they sized it relative to the largest capitals in the font as would be expected but then they decided that the lowercase letters looked too small so a few years later they revised it so that any given point size was about 4x larger than other fonts.

### If you don't have a headache, read some more..

There's some good information on Wikipedia about modern typography and origins; and other relevant subjects.

- [Point (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography))
- [Pixels per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixels_per_inch)
- [Font metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Font_metrics)
- [Typographic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_unit)

### And some first-hand experience

If you want to get more first-hand understanding you can download the free font development tool [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) which is comparable to the non-free [FontLab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/) (either of these two being the popular choice among font developers in my experience).  Both also have active communities so you can find plenty of support when learning how to use them.

- [Fontlab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/)
- [Fontlab Fontographer](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/download-fontographer/)
- [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/)
- [Fontlab Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FontLab)
- [FontForge Documentation](http://fontforge.org/editexample.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was more aking as to *why* for the font-family "arial" and the font-size 14px the "M" would be 10px. But you answered that, too: `the actual size of one fonts glyphs vs another font are [...] dependent on [...] how the developer designed the font glyphs when creating the font`. Thanks!

Comment: @davidcondrey I appreciate the thoroughness with which this post has been written, having knowledge is one thing, and actually sharing it in this level of detail is next level!

Comment: @davidcondrey Very nice explanation! May I ask what is license of the image  you provided? I would like to use it for documenting code.

Comment: Descend and ascend are not including the line gap in just about any other source I've seen on the matter. Also the ascend normally goes up from the baseline.

Answer (score 8):

The answer regarding typesetting is excellent, but be aware css diverges from traditional typography in many cases.

In css the font-size determines the height of the "em-box". The em-box is a bounding box which can contain all letters of the font including ascenders and descenders. Informally you can think of font-size as the "j"-height, since a lower case j has both ascender and descender and therefore (in most fonts) uses the full em-box height.

This means most letters (like a capital M) will have space above and below in the em-box. The relative amount of space above and below a capital letter will vary between fonts, since some fonts have relatively larger or smaller ascenders and descenders. This is part of what stylistically sets fonts apart for each others.

You ask why font-size is including ascenders and descenders, ie. why it correspond to the height of the em-box, even though the height of most letters will be less than this. Well, since most texts *do* includes letters with ascenders and descenders, the em-box height indicates how much vertical space the text require (at minimum), which is quite useful!

An caveat: Some glyphs may even extend beyond the em-box in some fonts. For example the letter "Å" often extend above the em-box. This is a stylistic choice by the designer of the font.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a satisfying answer to a similar question, I found this graphic to be a lot of help...

http://static.splashnology.com/articles/Choosing-the-Best-Units/font-units-large.png
[image]

Comment: Try this https://web.archive.org/web/20111219182556/http://static.splashnology.com/articles/Choosing-the-Best-Units/font-units-large.png

Comment: thanks, i edited  and included it in your answer ;)  , you might want to improve a bit the edit

Comment: those down voting might do well to consider that I found the graphic and made this answer before the accepted answer integrated it.

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented to pin down exactly what the font-size corresponds to in terms of font-metrics (as shown in the diagram in davidcondrey's answer).

Testing on Safari, Chrome and Firefox on macOS, setting font-size to 100px seems to set the apparent size of difference between the ascender line and descender line to 100px.

Unfortunately, there's multiple meanings for the ascender and descender when talking about different font formats, so to disambiguate in the case of OpenType, we're talking about the '**Typo Ascender**' and the '**Typo Descender**' from the OS/2 table.

[OpenType CSS font-height diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjbKI.png)

An interactive illustration is available on the opentype.js glyph inspector https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html

When positioning the character (again in terms of OpenType metrics), browsers seem to consider y = 0 to be the **Ascender**, (which is *not* the same as the 'ascender line' in davidcondrey's diagram, but instead it's the ascender in the hhea table in OpenType). However, if CSS `line-height` is not set to `normal`, the position is offset by some amount but I think the rules here might be a bit more complex.

I expect there's more that factors in and it may be different between operating systems and browsers, however this is at least a good approximation.