# Line height not accurate?

Tags: css

Someone probably had the same issue, but can't find anything. It seems like line-height css doesn't match the actual height of the line

Here is the text css properties:

```
.description{
    line-height:17px;
    font-size:14px;
    height:85px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

so normally, since 17px * 5 = 85px, we should only see 5 lines, but as you can see on the pic, the top of the next line is showing up. It behave like if line-height is about 16.7px and not 17px. Is there a way to correct that?

I try with different height (102px, 170px, etc..) , and the higher the box is, bigger the gap is (at 255px, we can see half of the next line )

[image]

**Update**: A comparison of my result with 255px box (issue) and the expected result (like jsfiddle)

js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eo7pkzqt/28/
[image]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle version, sometimes it happen for side impact.

Comment: oddly, with the exact same configuration in fiddle, it work just fine (same browser Chrome)

Comment: @LGSon how is this duplicate? you answer doesn't answer to the question

Comment: also using your own answer : 'Conclusion
Line-height defines div height, unless line-height is very small, in which case the font-size will define the size' so clearly the answer

Comment: Adjust the zoom level and see how the overlap changes. This is a classic cumulative rounding error.

Comment: @Alohci thx man , it seems very plausible, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336177/font-size-vs-line-height-vs-actual-height)

See line-he is depended on `font-size`,`font-family`....etc so variation comes using line-height

Comment: so you'r saying that if i set line-height to 20px, it won't be 20px? that will be odd. In that case why is it working with the fiddle but not in my version. Am I missing something?