# A part of letters below baseline becomes invisible when truncate the text by `overflow`, `white-space` and `text-overflow`

Tags: html, css

The default font is depends on browser, so in Windows/Chrome environment I noticed that it to truncate text by `overflow`, `white-space`, `text-overflow`, the part of text below underline becomes invisible.

[image]

For `font-size: 14px` and `line-height: 14px` all letters are almost visible, just a part of `g` letter has been cropped. For `font-size: 12px` and `line-height: 12px`, the visibility is worse: the lower part of `j` and `g` has been cropped:

```css
.test1{
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background: lightsalmon;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.spacer{
  height: 30px;
}

.test2{
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  background: lightsalmon;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">jane glad TestThatVerHardToBreakAlasdfjsdfjkjsdfjkosdfjoisdfjiosdfijdsfijowioqjrfiwqjfiw</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="test2">jane glad TestThatVerHardToBreakAlasdfjsdfjkjsdfjkosdfjoisdfjiosdfijdsfijowioqjrfiwqjfiw</div>
```

Of course if we change the line height, text becomes fully visible. But:

1. I don't want to change the `line-height: 1;` for single-line elements.
2. Even I need change line-height, I need to do some experiments to select the line-height value such as text will be fully visible. So, the line-height value will be hard-coded.

Is here some solution which does not depend on font size and line height?

Comment: Try increasing the `line-height`. For me, I always use a higher value for `line-height` than the `font-size`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41336508/8798220

Comment: *I don't want to change the line-height: 1; for single-line elements.* --> you **have** to change line-height. Using 1 as value is very bad: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif, oh, I see. It was a lot of discussions, but how can I select the optimal line height?

Comment: There is no optimal line-height. You simply need to make it big enough to contain the text (by default browser set it around 1.2 so you should not make it less than this value or you will have overflow and text cut)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, long time no see! Do you have some kind of list of overhanging characters (like "j", "g", "Ç", "Ĥ") to test the correct truncating?