# Font-Size out of phase

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this problem in html and SCSS, the word goes out of the defined box becouse the Font-size
Any way to solve it?

[image]

Here is my code

**SCSS**

```
.c-title { font-size: 60px !important; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); font-weight: 900; margin-bottom: 10px !important; height: 60px; }
```

**HTML** (I tried with h1, span, and div)

```
<div class="c-title">CPO</div>
```

Comment: Please check if other CSS rules have cascaded down to affect the display and provide that info; the fact that you're using `!important` tells me there are other rules in play. It could even be an issue with the specific font you're using, so best to tell us that too.

Comment: Try without `height` (or change it to `min-height`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [font-size vs line-height vs actual height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336177/font-size-vs-line-height-vs-actual-height)