# Specific font cause overlapping bug on text

Tags: html, css, overlap

I use a library which allows the selection of a font.

If I use the font Verdana, the graphic render this :

[image]

But if I use Roboto it renders as :

[image]

In the browser inspector the CSS is :

[image]

Why a specific font render correctly and not another one ?

Comment: This might help you understand what's going on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520410/when-setting-a-font-size-in-css-what-is-the-real-height-of-the-letters  . monospace fonts will use the same amount of space, others will do depending on their own character's specifities. We are missing your HTML and CSS demonstarting your issue anyhow.

Comment: Why are you using `font-size: 1.2px`? That's far too small to be legible.