Is it possible to visualize subscript and superscript letter elements with CSS?
Many languages have letters with superscript elements (b, d; ل لا; პ, ქ; б, ё) and subscript elements (j, g; ق غ; გ, კ; у, р), but for an isolated letter it's not always clear whether it has one, until we put it near another one (პკ).
I wonder if I can visualize them main part of the line vs sub/superscript elements using just CSS by either adding borders or colorizing the "main line" (from baseline to x-height).
I know that there are units ex, cap (beside em) related to this, but for instance the following attempt doesn't work as expected: the idea is that height 1cap should cover all the letters except for the subscript elements:


.text-elements-visualization {
  background: green;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 1cap;
}
<div class="text-elements-visualization">
  abj
</div>



but as you can see, this is not the case:

How can I fix the provided snippet so that the color covers the whole letters except for the subscript elements? Could you provide a similar solution for superscript elements (or, ideally, for both, with color line of 1ex shifted to the precise location)?

this will be closely related to the font. not all the fonts have the same metrics

@TemaniAfif do you mean that browser doesn't (always) deduce the em/ex/cap values from the font, but rather uses some default proportions between them?

the cap is the height of the capital letter but when setting the height browser start calculating from the top of the element and capital letter doesn't start from the top: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25520410/8620333 .. so aligning cap with the capital letters won't be easy

@TemaniAfif great diagram in the first answer, thanks, I'll study it in more detail

Providing you only need a single line of text depicted this way, you can use an empty inline-block ::before pseudo-element. Since it's empty, it will be aligned with its bottom on the baseline. You can then use its background to show the ex and cap height above that baseline. Like this:


body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.text-elements-visualization::before {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;          /* As wide as the container ... */
  margin-right: -100%;  /* ... but take up no space     */
}
.text-elements-visualization.ex::before {
  height: 1ex;
  background-color: palegreen;
}
.text-elements-visualization.cap::before {
  height: 1cap;
  background-color: moccasin;
}
.text-elements-visualization.both::before {
  height: 1cap;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    moccasin calc(1cap - 1ex), 
    palegreen calc(1cap - 1ex)
  );
}
<div class="text-elements-visualization ex">
  abj Hx b, d; ل لا; პ, ქ; б, ё, j, g; ق غ; გ, კ; у, р
</div>
<div class="text-elements-visualization cap">
  abj Hx b, d; ل لا; პ, ქ; б, ё, j, g; ق غ; გ, კ; у, р
</div>
<div class="text-elements-visualization both">
  abj Hx b, d; ل لا; პ, ქ; б, ё, j, g; ق غ; გ, კ; у, р
</div>




Great job, thanks! I was thinking about most of the bits you've mentioned (the pseudo-element, aligning to the baseline, using calc), but haven't come up with the negative margin trick, great idea!
